# Operating on a class with many template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a function that operates on a type with many template arguments.  For example:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, int MinSize, int MaxSize>
struct Foo {
   // ...
};
```

My function can operate on any `Foo` - I don't care about the template arguments.  I can write a function template to accept these objects:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, int MinSize, int MaxSize>
void do_work(const Foo<A, B, C, MinSize, MaxSize>& foo) {
   // ...
}
```

This works fine but seems a bit verbose.  It gets even worse if `do_work` is already a template.  The number of template arguments gets high very fast and I think it becomes hard to understand.  Is this something I should be concerned about or does this sort of thing happen all the time?

Is there another way I could write `do_work` so that I don't have to include all of `Foo`'s template arguments?  Perhaps using a more general template and a `static_assert` to make sure I get a `Foo`?

```
template <typename FooType>
void do_work(const FooType& foo) {
   // make sure foo is a 'Foo<...>'
   static_assert(??)
}
```

Comment: You could just not care and use the second version without a static assertion. If the user passes the wrong argument, there will probably be an error.

Comment: That's a totally valid answer too.  I'm just wondering if there's some TMP black magic that might make that error a little easier to diagnose.

Comment: You can use sfinae to check if the object has the right interface to do your work

Comment: @zmb: There is, but it would only start being  less verbose than spelling out the arguments if you have a lot of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

How about a variadic template:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void do_work(const Foo<Args...>& foo) { /* ... */ }
```

You won't get at the individual template arguments easily, though, but maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the static_assert() idea is not bad, actually, because it makes the assumption about the nature of foo explicit. You statically assert that the type has a static boolean member called is_foo that is set to true.

```
static_assert(FooType::is_foo);
```

And this will return true only if you define

```
template <class C, ...>
class Foo {
public:
   static bool const is_foo = true;
}
```